# `vault secrets` doesn't seem to exist

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm going through the [vault getting started guide](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/install.html) and I'm on the [secrets engines section](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/secrets-engines.html).

I'm running the vault v0.9.1 dev server on Arch Linux and have also tried the same thing on vault:0.9.1 from the docker hub.
All commands relating to `vault secrets` don't work and only bring up `help` which doesn't even list the `secrets` parameter. I've looked at the [changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#091-december-21st-2017) and this doesn't seem to have been changed.

For example:

`$ vault secrets enable -path=kv kv
$ vault secrets list`

My `vault status` output:

```
$ vault status                                                                                                                                                           
Seal Type: shamir
Sealed: false
Key Shares: 1
Key Threshold: 1
Unseal Progress: 0
Unseal Nonce:
Version: 0.9.1
Cluster Name: vault-cluster-958906bd
Cluster ID: 4d02dc0b-5541-c68c-9a2d-75b9cedc7f09


High-Availability Enabled: false
```

```

Comment: Could someone please add "vault" and "hashicorp" tags on server fault. I'm surprised they exist on stack overflow and not on server fault. I would but I need a minimum rep of 300 to add a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are using is enabled in the new CLI which was released as part of Vault's 0.9.2 release. Using a newer release should solve the problem.